# to store values with % into column of datatype decimal(28,9)

Tags: sql

I use the following code to substring values from text file and store in a table:

```
CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Record,82,11))=1 
        THEN (LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING (Record,82,11),',','')AS DECIMAL(28,14)))))
        ELSE NULL
END
```

the problem I'm facing is that when the substring contains value like `'0.098467%'`, null values are updated in the table. Could someone please help me resolve this.

Comment: `0.098467%` <--- this is not a decimal, so you cannot store it in a decimal column.

Comment: What would you like to do with such strings?

Comment: can something be added to my else condition to store such data

Comment: Store it in `varchar`

Comment: **How** do you want to store them? Removing `%`?

Comment: I'd recommend storing the decimal without the %. Your view/viewer/UI/report can display the %

Comment: yeah! without the % i can store it, but i guess isnummeric condition is failing when it checks the substring to have value like '0.098467%', I want to store the data 0.098467 in my column

Comment: You'll have to replace the % character prior to passing it through isnumeric() and cast(). Do it just like you're already doing with commas.

Comment: Which dbms? (ISNUMERIC, LTRIM and RTRIM are product specific functions.)